# Making CakePHP 2.0 work on a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, routes, cakephp-2.0

I have my site www.mysite.com in  /var/www/
and I added my cakephp app in  /var/www/developer

when I go to www.mysite.com/developer I get the login page fine and after I login the app takes me to the home page OK. But whenever I click on other link I get
*"Page not found"*

I have 3 htaccess

```
/var/www/developer
/var/www/developer/app
/var/www/developer/app/webroot
```

What should I put on those to make my urls work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .htaccess files should probably look like this:

/var/www/developer

```php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

/var/www/developer/app

```php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

/var/www/developer/app/webroot

```php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

You also should have right paths defined in /var/www/developer/app/webroot/index.php

instead of

```php
    if (!defined('ROOT')) {
        define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
    }
```

try something specify the right way (eq. DS . 'www' . 'develop')
usually it is enough to redefine just CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH but sometimes youe needed define all three ROOT WEBROOT_DIR nad CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH